# Point-free in Haskell

Tags: haskell, coding-style, pointfree

I have this code that I want to make point-free;

`(\k t -> chr $ a + flip mod 26 (ord k + ord t -2*a))`

How do I do that?

Also are there some general rules for point free style other than "think about this amd come up with something"?

Comment: Why would you want to make that point-free?

Comment: Because being able to write point-free code looks like one of the properties of a good Haskell programmer.

Comment: Sometimes point-free code is clearer than its non-point-free alternative, and then it's a good idea to use point-free style. This is not one of those times.

Comment: Well, you can always do SKI factorization as described in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic#Completeness_of_the_S-K_basis, with S = Control.Monad.ap, K = const, and I = id.  But that is pretty distant from what Haskellers do to make code point free.  I learned from many, many experiences analyzing my code and trying to make it prettier, and learning about new combinators such as Control.Arrow.(***, &&&), applicative notation, Data.Function.on, etc.

Comment: Point-free code is usually the mark of a very crazy genius. Point-free code is sometimes the mark of a good Haskell programmer. I don't think this is one of the cases where you can make a simple translation into point-free code.

Comment: does expressing functions in a point free way allow for some compile optimisations that you wouldn't get otherwise? I think I read that some place, some time.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

To turn a function

```
func x y z = (some expression in x, y and z)
```

into point-free form, I generally try to follow what is done to the last parameter `z` and write the function as

```
func x y z = (some function pipeline built using x and y) z
```

Then I can cancel out the `z`s to get

```
func x y = (some function pipeline built using x and y)
```

Then repeating the process for y and x should end up with `func` in point-free form.  An essential transformation to recognise in this process is:

```
    f z = foo $ bar z    -- or f z = foo (bar z)
<=> f z = foo . bar $ z
<=> f   = foo . bar
```

It's also important to remember that with partial evaluation, you can "break off" the last argument to a function:

```
foo $ bar x y == foo . bar x $ y    -- foo applied to ((bar x) applied to y)
```

For your particular function, consider the flow that `k` and `t` go through:

1. Apply `ord` to each of them
2. Add the results
3. Subtract 2*a
4. Take the result mod 26
5. Add a
6. Apply `chr`

So as a first attempt at simplifying, we get:

```
func k t = chr . (+a) . (`mod` 26) . subtract (2*a) $ ord k + ord t
```

Note that you can avoid `flip` by using a section on `mod`, and sections using `-` get messy in Haskell so there's a `subtract` function (they clash with the syntax for writing negative numbers: `(-2)` means negative 2, and isn't the same as `subtract 2`).

In this function, `ord k + ord t` is an excellent candidate for using `Data.Function.on` ([link](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Function.html#v:on)).  This useful combinator lets us replace `ord k + ord t` with a function applied to `k` and `t`:

```
func k t = chr . (+a) . (`mod` 26) . subtract (2*a) $ ((+) `on` ord) k t
```

We're now very close to having

```
func k t = (function pipeline) k t
```

and hence

```
func = (function pipeline)
```

Unfortunately Haskell is a bit messy when it comes to composing a binary function with a sequence of unary functions, but there is a trick (I'll see if I can find a good reference for it), and we end up with:

```
import Data.Function (on)

func = ((chr . (+a) . (`mod` 26) . subtract (2*a)) .) . ((+) `on` ord)
```

which is almost a nice neat point-free function pipeline, except for that ugly composing trick.  By defining the `.:` operator suggested in the comments [on this page](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/a9tb2/secret_haskell_operators/), this tidies up a little to:

```
import Data.Function (on)

(.:) = (.).(.)

func = (chr . (+a) . (`mod` 26) . subtract (2*a)) .: ((+) `on` ord)
```

To polish this some more, you could add some helper functions to separate the letter <-> Int conversion from the [Caesar cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) arithmetic.  For example: `letterToInt = subtract a . ord`

Comment: `subtract (2*a)` == `(+(-2*a))`.

Answer (score 10):

> Also are there some general rules for point free style other than "think about this amd come up with something"?

You can always cheat and use the "pl" tool from lambdabot (either by going to #haskell on freenode or by using e.g. [ghci on acid](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/GHCi#GHCi_on_Acid)). For your code pl gives:

`((chr . (a +) . flip mod 26) .) . flip flip (2 * a) . ((-) .) . (. ord) . (+) . ord`

Which isn't really an improvement if you ask me.

Answer (score 3):

There's definitely a set of tricks to transforming an expression into point-free style. I don't claim to be an expert, but here are some tips.

First, you want to isolate the function arguments in the right-most term of the expression. Your main tools here will be `flip` and `$`, using the rules:

```
f a b ==> flip f b a
f (g a) ==> f $ g a
```

where `f` and `g` are functions, and `a` and `b` are expressions. So to start:

```
(\k t -> chr $ a + flip mod 26 (ord k + ord t -2*a))
-- replace parens with ($)
(\k t -> chr $ (a +) . flip mod 26 $ ord k + ord t - 2*a)
-- prefix and flip (-)
(\k t -> chr $ (a +) . flip mod 26 $ flip (-) (2*a) $ ord k + ord t)
-- prefix (+)
(\k t -> chr $ (a +) . flip mod 26 $ flip (-) (2*a) $ (+) (ord k) (ord t))
```

Now we need to get `t` out on the right hand side. To do this, use the rule:

```
f (g a) ==> (f . g) a
```

And so:

```
-- pull the t out on the rhs
(\k t -> chr $ (a +) . flip mod 26 $ flip (-) (2*a) $ ((+) (ord k) . ord) t)
-- flip (.) (using a section)
(\k t -> chr $ (a +) . flip mod 26 $ flip (-) (2*a) $ ((. ord) $ (+) (ord k)) t)
-- pull the k out
(\k t -> chr $ (a +) . flip mod 26 $ flip (-) (2*a) $ ((. ord) . ((+) . ord)) k t)
```

Now, we need to turn everything to the left of `k` and `t` into one big function term, so that we have an expression of the form `(\k t -> f k t)`. This is where things get a bit mind-bending. To start with, note that all the terms up to the last `$` are functions with a single argument, so we can compose them:

```
(\k t -> chr . (a +) . flip mod 26 . flip (-) (2*a) $ ((. ord) . ((+) . ord)) k t)
```

Now, we have a function of type `Char -> Char -> Int` that we want to compose with a function of type `Int -> Char`, yielding a function of type `Char -> Char -> Char`. We can achieve that using the (very odd-looking) rule

```
f (g a b) ==> ((f .) . g) a b
```

That gives us:

```
(\k t -> (((chr . (a +) . flip mod 26 . flip (-) (2*a)) .) . ((. ord) . ((+) . ord))) k t)
```

Now we can just apply a beta reduction:

```
((chr . (a +) . flip mod 26) .) . (flip flip (2*a) . ((-) . ) . ((. ord) . (+) .ord))
```

Comment: Using the `->` instances of Monad, Applicative, or Arrow are also neat tricks.

Comment: `f (g a) ==> f $ g a` doesn't really help. The right hand side is still `f $ (g a)`. What you want is function composition. `f (g a)` is `(f . g) a`.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that the point of your point-freeing is to make the code more concise and more readable. I therefore think that it is wise to also do some other refactorings towards simplification which then might make it easier to remove the variables.

```
(\k t -> chr $ a + flip mod 26 (ord k + ord t - 2*a))
```

First of all, the `flip` is unnecessary:

```
(\k t -> chr $ a + (ord k + ord t - 2*a) `mod` 26)
```

Next, I would use *name and conquer* to factor out an independently usable subfunction:

```
encode_characters k t = chr $ encode (ord k) (ord t)
encode x y = (x + y - 2*a) `mod` 26 + a
```

I also gave a name to the first expression to make it clearer and reusable. `encode_characters` is now easy to make point-free using the technique from @Nefrubyr:

```
encode_characters = chr . encode `on` ord
```

As for the second expression, I cannot produce a form that's more readable than any shown in the other answers and they're all less readable than the point-wise form. I would therefore suggest to stop refactoring at this point and admire the cleanliness and reusability of the resulting code.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

PS: as an exercise, depending on the context of the problem, some slight modification of the function interfaces (what data in what form is passed into the functions) might yield more simplifications by generalizing the problem.

A. Implement and simplify function `encode_n_characters :: [Char] -> Char` where `encode_characters k t = encode_n_characters [k, t]`. Is the result simpler than the specialized two-argument function?

B. Implement a function `encode'` defined via `encode' (x + y) = encode x y` and reimplement `encode_characters` using this function. Does either of the functions become simpler? Is the implementation simpler overall? Is `encode'` more or less reusable than `encode`?

Answer (score 0):

Connect on [IRC, #haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/IRC_channel), and [ask lambdabot !](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree):

```
<you> @pl (\k t -> chr $ a + flip mod 26 (ord k + ord t -2*a))
<lambdabot> [the answer]
```

Comment: Not already posted because I'm trying to figure it out by hand, instead of asking lambdabot... An edit is coming.

Comment: Bah, I came up with let f1 = \a -> (chr .) . ((a+).).((flip mod 26).).(.ord).(+).((-) (2*a)) . ord    -- but it gives the wrong results and I don't feel like debugging it now :)