# Point-free style and using $

Tags: haskell, pointfree

How does one combine using `$` and point-free style?

A clear example is the following utility function:

```
times :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
times n xs = concat $ replicate n xs
```

Just writing `concat $ replicate` produces an error, similarly you can't write `concat . replicate` either because `concat` expects a value and not a function.

So how would you turn the above function into point-free style?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464406/point-free-in-haskell

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use this combinator: (The colon hints that two arguments follow)

```
(.:) :: (c -> d) -> (a -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> d
(.:) = (.) . (.)
```

It allows you to get rid of the `n`:

```
time = concat .: replicate
```

Comment: @dave4420 Well, IMHO `.:` is much more mnemnoric

Comment: I personally prefer `.*`, so that the next ones can be `.**`, `.***`, etc. Either way, we should try to get `.:` into Haskell Prime's Prelude, or at least into base libraries.

Comment: Is `fmap fmap fmap` a generalization of `.:`?

Comment: @nponeccop Yes, but one is like (.), so it's rather fmap .  fmap.

Answer (score 13):

You can easily write an almost point-free version with

```
times n  =  concat . replicate n
```

A fully point-free version can be achieved with explicit curry and uncurry:

```
times  =  curry $ concat . uncurry replicate
```

Comment: IMHO the last one is unneccessarily complicated since it involves needless `curry` and `uncurry`, see the answer of Josh and me.

Comment: @FUZxxl: I know, I upvoted your answer, we're now both at +3.

Comment: Another +1 for the almost point-free version. While I recommend wider adoption of `.:`, I also recommend sticking with "almost" point-free for more convoluted cases.

Comment: @Dan Well, completely pointfree is often considered too pointless, at least by me.

Comment: and by me :) Adapt the degree of point-free to your skills and taste. There are some fundamental flaws with point free style which can be observed by studying combinatory logic - the ultimate pointfree calculus. Also take a look at Tony Hoare's work on function-based programming.

Answer (score 12):

Get on freenode and ask lambdabot ;)

```
<jleedev> @pl \n xs -> concat $ replicate n xs
<lambdabot> (join .) . replicate
```

Comment: Note that `(foo . ) . bar` is lambdabot's typical pattern for `foo .: bar`, since `.:` is apparently not considered in the poitless-ing process.

Answer (score 3):

In Haskell, function composition is associative¹:

```
f . g . h == (f . g) . h == f . (g . h)
```

Any [infix operator](https://wiki.haskell.org/Infix_operator) is just a good ol' function:

```
2 + 3 == (+) 2 3
f 2 3 = 2 `f` 3
```

A [composition operator](https://wiki.haskell.org/Function_composition) is just a binary function too, a [higher-order](https://wiki.haskell.org/Higher_order_function) one, it accepts 2 functions and returns a function:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
```

Therefore any composition operator can be rewritten as such:

```
f . g == (.) f g
f . g . h == (f . g) . h == ((.) f g) . h == (.) ((.) f g) h
f . g . h == f . (g . h) == f . ((.) g h) == (.) f ((.) g h)
```

Every function in Haskell can be [partially applied](https://wiki.haskell.org/Partial_application) due to [currying](https://wiki.haskell.org/Currying) by default. Infix operators can be partially applied in a very concise way, using [sections](https://wiki.haskell.org/Section_of_an_infix_operator):

```
(-) == (\x y -> x - y)
(2-) == (-) 2 == (\y -> 2 - y)
(-2) == flip (-) 2 == (\x -> (-) x 2) == (\x -> x - 2)
(2-) 3 == -1
(-2) 3 == 1
```

As composition operator is just an ordinary binary function, you can use it in sections too:

```
f . g == (.) f g == (f.) g == (.g) f
```

Another interesting binary operator is [$](https://wiki.haskell.org/$), which is just function application:

```
f x == f $ x
f x y z == (((f x) y) z) == f x y z
f(g(h x)) == f $ g $ h $ x == f . g . h $ x == (f . g . h) x
```

With this knowledge, how do I transform `concat $ replicate n xs` into point-free style?

```
times n xs = concat $ replicate n xs
times n xs = concat $ (replicate n) xs
times n xs = concat $ replicate n $ xs
times n xs = concat . replicate n $ xs
times n    = concat . replicate n
times n    = (.) concat (replicate n)
times n    = (concat.) (replicate n) -- concat is 1st arg to (.)
times n    = (concat.) $ replicate n
times n    = (concat.) . replicate $ n
times      = (concat.) . replicate
```

¹<sup>Haskell is based on [category theory](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Category_theory). A category in category theory consists of 3 things: some **objects**, some **morphisms**, and a notion of **composition** of morphisms. Every morphism connects a *source object* with a *target object*, one-way. Category theory requires composition of morphisms to be associative. A category that is used in Haskell is called **Hask**, whose objects are types and whose morphisms are functions. A function `f :: Int -> String` is a morphism that connects object `Int` to object `String`. Therefore category theory requires Haskell's function compositions to be associative.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

By extending FUZxxl's answer, we got

```
(.:) :: (c -> d) -> (a -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> d
(.:) = (.).(.)

(.::) :: (d -> e) -> (a -> b -> c -> d) -> a -> b -> c -> e
(.::) = (.).(.:)

(.:::) :: (e -> f) -> (a -> b -> c -> d -> e) -> a -> b -> c -> d -> f
(.:::) = (.).(.::)

...
```

Very nice.

**Bonus**

```
(.:::) :: (e -> f) -> (a -> b -> c -> d -> e) -> a -> b -> c -> d -> f
(.:::) = (.:).(.:)
```

Emm... so maybe we should say

```
(.1) = .

(.2) :: (c -> d) -> (a -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> d
(.2) = (.1).(.1)

(.3) :: (d -> e) -> (a -> b -> c -> d) -> a -> b -> c -> e
(.3) = (.1).(.2)
-- alternatively, (.3) = (.2).(.1)

(.4) :: (e -> f) -> (a -> b -> c -> d -> e) -> a -> b -> c -> d -> f
(.4) = (.1).(.3)
-- alternative 1 -- (.4) = (.2).(.2)
-- alternative 2 -- (.4) = (.3).(.1)
```

Even better.

We can also extend this to

```
fmap2 :: (Functor f, Functor g) => (a -> b) -> f (g a) -> f (g b)
fmap2 f = fmap (fmap f)

fmap4 :: (Functor f, Functor g, Functor h, functro i) 
   => (a -> b) -> f (g (h (i a))) -> f (g (h (i b)))
fmap4 f = fmap2 (fmap2 f)
```

which follows the same pattern.

It would be even better to have the times of applying `fmap` or `(.)` parameterized. However, those `fmap` or `(.)`s are actually different on type. So the only way to do this would be using compile time calculation, for example `TemplateHaskell`.

For everyday uses, I would simply suggest

```
Prelude> ((.).(.)) concat replicate 5 [1,2]
[1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2]
Prelude> ((.).(.).(.)) (*10) foldr (+) 3 [2,1]
60
```