# composing functions with higher arity

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I don't understand composing functions with arity > 1.
in ghci 7.4.1 i typed:

```
((*).succ) 3 4
> 16
```

i don't fully understand the math transformation but it's clear that it's the same as

```
(*) (succ 3) 4
```

but when i do:

```
( (\x y z -> x).(\a b -> a*b) ) 2 3 4 5
> 10
( (\x y z -> y).(\a b -> a*b) ) 2 3 4 5
> No instance for (Num (a0 -> t0))
```

and now i'm totally lost. can anyone explain what happens? ps. I know that everything in haskell has only 1 parameter but it doesn't really help me :)

Comment: The other little thing to know about Haskell is that function application is left-associative.

Comment: See [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17585649/composing-function-composition-how-does-work/17586180#17586180) for details on `(.).(.)` which is a bit of a funny idiom useful for composing multi-arity functions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Work it out this way:

```
(f . g) x = f (g x)
(f . g) x y = f (g x) y -- applying y
```

Then replace f with `(*)`, g with `succ` and x and y with their values:

```
((*) . succ) 3 4 = (*) (succ 3) 4
                 = (*) 4 4
                 = 16
```

Answer (score 5):

When you compose `(\x y z -> x) . (\a b -> a*b)` you compose functions of the following signatures:

```
(\x y z -> x) :: a -> b -> c -> a
(\a b -> a*b) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

The signature of `(.)` is

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

Now, let's put things together to get a specialized version of signature of `(.)` for those functions.

1. First we specialize the `(b -> c)` part of `(.)` signature to `a -> b -> c -> a`:

   ```
   (b -> (z -> x -> b)) -> (a -> b) -> a -> (z -> x -> b)
   ```

   Get it? The `c` becomes `(z -> x -> b)`.
2. Now let's specialize the `(a -> b)` part of `(.)` signature to `a -> a -> a`:

   ```
   ((a -> a) -> (z -> x -> (a -> a))) -> (a -> (a -> a)) -> a -> (z -> x -> (a -> a))
   ```

   The `b` becomes `(a -> a)`.
3. Now let's drop the redundant braces:

   ```
   ((a -> a) -> z -> x -> a -> a) -> (a -> a -> a) -> a -> z -> x -> a -> a
   ```
4. Now here's a session from ghci showing how the signature changes while I consequently apply all the arguments to a function of that signature:

   ```
   > let f = undefined :: ((a -> a) -> z -> x -> a -> a) -> (a -> a -> a) -> a -> z -> x -> a -> a
   > :t f (\x y z -> x)
   f (\x y z -> x) :: (a -> a -> a) -> a -> z -> x -> a -> a
   > :t f (\x y z -> x) (\a b -> a*b)
   f (\x y z -> x) (\a b -> a*b) :: Num a => a -> z -> x -> a -> a
   > :t f (\x y z -> x) (\a b -> a*b) 2
   f (\x y z -> x) (\a b -> a*b) 2 :: Num a => z -> x -> a -> a
   > :t f (\x y z -> x) (\a b -> a*b) 2 3
   f (\x y z -> x) (\a b -> a*b) 2 3 :: Num a => x -> a -> a
   > :t f (\x y z -> x) (\a b -> a*b) 2 3 4
   f (\x y z -> x) (\a b -> a*b) 2 3 4 :: Num a => a -> a
   > :t f (\x y z -> x) (\a b -> a*b) 2 3 4 5
   f (\x y z -> x) (\a b -> a*b) 2 3 4 5 :: Num a => a
   ```

The above explains how `( (\x y z -> x).(\a b -> a*b) ) 2 3 4 5` works.

Now here's how `( (\x y z -> y).(\a b -> a*b) ) 2 3 4 5` translates:

```
((a -> a) -> z -> x -> z) -> (a -> a -> a) -> a -> z -> x -> z
```

And here are the session results:

```
> let f = undefined :: ((a -> a) -> z -> x -> z) -> (a -> a -> a) -> a -> z -> x -> z
> :t f (\x y z -> x)
f (\x y z -> x) :: (a -> a -> a) -> a -> (a -> a) -> x -> a -> a
> :t f (\x y z -> x) (\a b -> a*b)
f (\x y z -> x) (\a b -> a*b)
  :: Num a => a -> (a -> a) -> x -> a -> a
> :t f (\x y z -> x) (\a b -> a*b) 2
f (\x y z -> x) (\a b -> a*b) 2 :: Num a => (a -> a) -> x -> a -> a
> :t f (\x y z -> x) (\a b -> a*b) 2 3
f (\x y z -> x) (\a b -> a*b) 2 3
  :: (Num a, Num (a -> a)) => x -> a -> a
```

The last line explains your error message. There obviously can't be any `Num` instance for `a -> a`.

Answer (score 3):

Since you understand everything is a one-argument function, let's start from that point. Keep in mind that (\x y z -> x) is really (\x -> (\y z -> x)), which in turn really is (\x -> (\y -> (\z -> x))), but let's stop at the first step to keep the noise from brackets down.

`(f . g) x = f (g x)`

hence

```
((\x -> (\y z -> x)) . (\a b -> a*b)) 2 =
(\x -> (\y z -> x)) ((\a -> (\b -> a*b)) 2) =
(\x -> (\y z -> x)) (\b -> 2*b) =
(\y z -> (\b -> 2*b))
```

Now remember the second step and expand (\y z -> ...):

```
(\y z -> (\b -> 2*b)) 3 4 =
(\y -> (\z -> (\b -> 2*b))) 3 4 =
   -- \y -> ... given anything, returns a function \z -> ...
(\z -> (\b -> 2*b)) 4 =
   -- \z -> ... given anything, returns a function \b -> ...
(\b -> 2*b)
```

which finally is:

```
(\b -> 2*b) 5 = 2*5 = 10
```

The story unfolds differently, if the first function returns y instead of x:

```
((\x -> (\y z -> y)) . (\a -> (\b -> a*b))) 2 =
(\x -> (\y z -> y)) ((\a -> (\b -> a*b)) 2) =
(\x -> (\y z -> y)) (\b -> 2*b) =
   -- \x -> ... given anything, returns a function \y z -> ...
(\y z -> y)
```

so you get:

```
(\y -> (\z -> y)) 3 4 5 =
   -- \y -> ... given anything, returns a function \z -> ...
(\z -> 3) 4 5 =
   -- \z -> ... given anything, returns a constant 3
3 5  -- now still trying to apply 5 to 3
```

It is attempting to treat `3` as a function that can take `5`.

Answer (score 2):

Combinator `.` is a [function composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition) operator. Let's examine its type:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

So it takes the result of the second function and passes it to the first function.

In your example, the important thing to consider is that we can view `*` as a single-argmuent function whose result is a function:

```
(*) :: Num a => a -> (a -> a)
```

It takes a number and returns a function that multiplies its argument by the number. (This approach is called [Currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)). The type operator `->` associates to the right, so the parentheses are optional - its just in our minds, if we view `(*)` as a two-argument function returning a number or a one-argument function returning another function.

This helps us view what `(*) . succ` does: It increments its argument (which must be `Enum`), and then converts it into a function that multiplies its argument by the number (so the argument must also be `Num`). The result is then

```
(*) . succ :: (Enum a, Num a) => a -> (a -> a)
```

Again, we can view it as a one-argument function, or more conveniently two-argument function: It increments its first argument and multiplies it with the second.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
( (\x y z -> x).(\a b -> a*b) ) 2 3 4 5
```

1. they first evaluate (\a b -> a*b) 2 resulting in function like this (\b -> 2*b)
2. then evaluate (\x y z -> x) (\b -> 2*b) 3 4 that say that take the function take the 3 and take the 4 and return the function, something like this: ((\b -> 2*b) 3 4 -> (\b -> 2*b))
3. and only remains (\b -> 2*b) 5 resulting  2*5 = 10

but in

```
( (\x y z -> y).(\a b -> a*b) ) 2 3 4 5
```

the second evaluation will result in this ((\b -> 2*b) 3 4 -> 3) remaining 3 5 causing a error