# point free notation with multiple function parameters

Tags: pointfree, elm

I am trying to port the following Haskell code (http://codepad.org/MMydRCxo)

```
foo :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Maybe Bool
foo a b c = if a == 1 then Just True else Nothing

bar :: Int -> Int -> Bool
bar b c = maybe False id $ foo 1 b c

-- point free
bar' :: Int -> Int -> Bool
bar' = ((maybe False id $) .) . foo 1

main = do
  print $ bar 2 3
  print $ bar' 2 3
```

to Elm, but had no luck yet. (http://share-elm.com/sprout/5271f160e4b03cf6e675bc97)

```
foo : Int -> Int -> Int -> Maybe Bool
foo a b c = if a == 1 then Just True else Nothing

bar : Int -> Int -> Bool
bar b c = maybe False id <| foo 1 b c

-- point free
bar' : Int -> Int -> Bool
bar' = ((maybe False id <|) .) . foo 1

main = flow down [
    asText <| bar 2 3
  , asText <| bar' 2 3]
```

Any Ideas if there is a possibility to make this work point free in Elm? :)

Dobi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try getting rid of the `<|` and using the composition function in prefix notation instead. 
It'll first create a function that takes an argument, and have *that* function compose `foo 1`.

That way, calling `bar' 2` will return the composed function that takes the last argument.
I.e. (http://share-elm.com/sprout/52720bc5e4b03cf6e675bcc8):

```
foo : Int -> Int -> Int -> Maybe Bool
foo a b c = if a == 1 then Just True else Nothing

bar : Int -> Int -> Bool
bar b c = maybe False id <| foo 1 b c

bar' : Int -> Int -> Bool
bar' = (.) (maybe False id) . foo 1
-- the explicit evaluation precedence being: ((.) (maybe False id)) . (foo 1)

main = flow down [
    asText <| bar 2 3
  , asText <| bar' 2 3]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. So you convert the operator section to prefix notation with partial application, clever: (x .) = (.) x

Answer (score 3):

In Haskell, the following expressions are all equivalent:

```
(f .) . g
(.) f . g
(.) ((.) f) g
((.).(.)) f g
(\x y -> f (g x y))
```

This means that `f` is an unary function, `g` is a binary function, 2 parameters are passed to `g`, whose result is passed to `f`. Read more about [“owl” operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30873529/596361) to understand how it works.

So if you want to convert a similar expression to Elm, you would one of the following:

```
(.:) = (<<)<<(<<) -- owl operator definition
(<<) f << g
(<<) ((<<) f) g
f .: g
```

For example:

```
((<<) negate << (+)) 3 4 -- returns -7
(negate .: (+)) 3 4      -- returns -7
```

*Note: in [Elm 0.13](http://elm-lang.org/blog/announce/0.13) `(.)` is replaced by `(<<)`, while `(>>)` is now the same as `flip (<<)`*