# Transforming a Haskell function to a point free representaion

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform, pointfree, purely-functional

I want to create a *pointfree* function that takes a list of functions, applies a single argument to each listed function, and then compresses the list via another function. A pointfree version of this function would have the following type signature:

`multiplex :: ([a] -> b) -> [(c -> a)] -> (c -> b)`

And an example usage:

```
invariantsHold :: (Integral a) => a -> Bool
invariantsHold = multiplex (all id) [(>=0),(<=50),even]
```

I was able to write the following:

```
multiplex :: ([a] -> b) -> [(c -> a)] -> c -> b
multiplex f xs e = f $ map ((flip ($)) e) xs
```

This implementation is not pointfree, *how can I transform this function to a pointfree representation?*

Comment: [Lambdabot](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Lambdabot) suggests this beauty: `(. flip (map . flip id)) . (.)`

Comment: @duplode I was looking for a documented function transformation like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8465619/1465011) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13426526/1465011). The goal is to try and make the function more readable while reducing the points in the definition. Lambdabot's "beauty" *while correct*, doesn't given me information necessary *to improve* the function.

Comment: I know; that is why I did not post it as an answer. In any case, `($ e)` instead of `((flip ($)) e)` would improve readability quite a bit.

Comment: If you swapped the `[c -> a]` and `c` then it's just `(.: map . flip ($))` where `(.:) = (.) . (.)`

Comment: @jozefg There's always: `((.: map . flip ($)) ^>) where (.:) = (.).(.); (^>) = flip . flip .(.) flip`

Comment: Your last one can be improved if you know that `map . flip ($)` is `flip sequence` for the `(->) a` Monad. After which you may want to switch `[c -> a]` and `c` back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in pointfree style, but surely could be simplified significantly by using `Applicative` (need to import `Control.Applicative`):

```
multiplex f xs e = f $ xs <*> pure e
```

`invariantsHold` also could be simplified a little:

```
invariantsHold = multiplex and [(>=0),(<=50),even]
```

---

Using `sequenceA` (from `Data.Traversable`) is another way to define this `multiplex`:

```
multiplex f xs e = f $ sequenceA xs e
```

And this definition can be rewritten in pointfree style (give by [`pointfree`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pointfree)):

```
multiplex = (. sequenceA) . (.)
```

or

```
multiplex = flip ((.) . (.)) sequenceA
```

Beautiful, but seems pointless to me :-)